# C++ Highscore List Debug Error

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, vector, data-structures

Edited Code: 
I am now able to write the clock time in the file, but the problem is, it's not exactly the clock time. It writes weird numbers such as 00F3D..  and so on. I have no idea if it is due because the clock's time contains a colon in it when it's in the string format, example: 0:12

```
// Used for Highscores
struct highscore
{
    char name[10]; 
    int zombiesKilled; 
    char Date[10];
    char *clock[10];
}; 

void highscoreBoard(int option, int zombKilled)
{
    int quanity = 0; 
    int playerScore = 0;        // the in Results for Highscores
    FILE *streaming; 
    highscore data[10];


    char *newClock = new char[clockData.clockTime.length() + 1]; 
    strcpy(newClock,clockData.clockTime.c_str());
    switch (option)
    {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `highscore` structure has `string clock` in it. Objects of type `string` are not suitable for writing directly to a file from memory, as they may contain pointers to other parts of memory.

Here are two solutions: either change `clock` to a char array like your other struct members, or don't use a binary write of the high scores, write the file as text instead (which is more complicated, but leads to a human readable file).

Comment: Hey Dark, I seemed to bypass the error now. I changed the string clock to a char[10], it writes in the file! But now the problem is it writes weird numbers such as 00F34D.. and so on. I edited my answer above to see if you can help me.

Comment: As far as I can tell `clock` should not be an array of pointers. Just use `char clock[10]`, then use strcpy to copy the value into it (assuming you can guarantee that you have less than 10 chars to copy). Don't assign to `clock[5]` as you are now, I am not sure what you meant by that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the file permissions after creating the file? It seems like the permissions have been set as no read, no write, no execute.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Check if you have proper permissions to read and write to the file.  Also, you didn't close the stream after opening it in read mode, but before you open in write mode in case 0.  Make sure you close all the streams before you open new ones.

Comment: I see! Alright, It's so weird. I am able to write in the file successfully, but right after I right into it, I can the error, but it still writes into the file!

Comment: And to your comment above, I thought I did close it in case 0? I put fclose (streaming)?

Comment: I would assume it is something to do with the file streams not being closed properly before you try to open them in different modes.

Comment: right, but you open streaming with the 'r' flag in the if statement, and open in 'wb' mode later in the file, without closing the first stream you opened

Comment: What should I properly put the closes in the file then? I thought I had them right since they were all at the end of the file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77361/discussion-between-holtc-and-ryan12345).

Comment: In case 0 you mean? Because if so, I put if it does not equal stream… and then if not open "wb" mode, and close "wb" mode.

Comment: @Ryan12345 This is all a moot point.  As the other answer given states, you can't write `std::string` to a file in this fashion.  So all of this effort in figuring out file permissions and such won't solve the underlying issue, which is proper serialization.